# SQL monthly statement using recursive cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to create a monthly bank account statement from a transaction table which has all history records.
I would like have opening balance as the first row and then the current months transaction with the updated balance at that time using recursive cte.
I know this can be done by table update too but recursion is what i am looking for.

the table structure would be like:

```
declare @temp table (date datetime,tran_id int,cust_id int,tran_type char,amount int)
insert into @temp values('2017-06-06 22:05:10.703',1,1,'c',700),
('2017-06-12 22:05:10.703',2,1,'d',100),('2017-06-20 22:05:10.703',3,1,'c',200),
('2017-06-26 22:05:10.703',4,1,'d',450),(getdate()+1,5,1,'d',200),
(getdate()+2,6,1,'d',200),(getdate()+3,7,1,'c',500),
(getdate()+4,8,1,'d',300),(getdate()+5,9,1,'d',200),
('2017-06-18 22:05:10.703',12,1,'d',100)
```

So in here there is transaction for month 6 and 7.
The opening balance of current month would be sum of all transactions in June which will be used as anchor to get recursive balance.
Now i would like the select query to have date,tran_id,cust_id,credit,debit,balance as the result set.

So if table has data like:

```
date                   tran_id  cust_id tran_type   amount
2017-06-06 22:05:10.703 1   1   c   700
2017-06-12 22:05:10.703 2   1   d   100
2017-06-20 22:05:10.703 3   1   c   200
2017-06-26 22:05:10.703 4   1   d   450
2017-07-08 16:34:24.817 5   1   d   200
2017-07-09 16:34:24.817 6   1   d   200
2017-07-10 16:34:24.817 7   1   c   500
2017-07-11 16:34:24.817 8   1   d   300
2017-07-12 16:34:24.817 9   1   d   200
2017-06-18 22:05:10.703 12  1   d   100

The monthly statement for month 7 should be like:
opening balance of 250

date                     tran_id    cust_id credit  debit   balance
2017-07-08 16:40:56.810     5        1      NULL     200    50
2017-07-09 16:40:56.810     6        1      NULL     200    -150
2017-07-10 16:40:56.810     7        1      500      NULL   350
2017-07-11 16:40:56.810     8        1      NULL     300    -50
2017-07-12 16:40:56.810     9        1      NULL     200    -250
```

i have tried using recursive cte and sum windowed  function but it does not give continuous balance just a row by row balance.

Also using aggregate functions in a cte is a no no so stuck at that too.

```
;with cte as
(
select cust_id,sum(case when tran_type='c' then amount*1 else amount*-1 end) 
as 'opening balance' from @temp 
where MONTH(date)=6 group by cust_id
),

cte2 as
(
select * from cte
union all
select t.cust_id,amount+[opening balance] as 'balance1' from @temp t join 
cte2 c on c.cust_id=t.cust_id
where MONTH(date)=7
)
select * from cte2
```

**OR**

```
;with cte as
(
select cust_id,sum(case when tran_type='c' then amount*1 else amount*-1 end) 
as 'opening balance' from @temp 
where MONTH(date)=6 group by cust_id
union all
select t.cust_id,SUM(amount+[opening balance]) as 'balance1' from @temp t 
join cte c on c.cust_id=t.cust_id
where MONTH(date)=7
)
select * from cte
option (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Can you add the expected result in table format

Comment: added the table with expected results

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older versions, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the running balance

```
;WITH opening_balance_cte
     AS (SELECT cust_id,
                Sum(CASE WHEN tran_type = 'c' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) AS opening_balance
         FROM   Yourtable
         WHERE  [date] < '2017-07-01'
         GROUP  BY cust_id)
SELECT *,
       balance
FROM   Yourtable a
       JOIN opening_balance_cte ob
         ON ob.cust_id = a.cust_id
       CROSS apply (SELECT ob.opening_balance + Sum(CASE WHEN tran_type = 'c' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) AS balance
                    FROM   Yourtable b
                    WHERE  a.cust_id = b.cust_id
                           AND a.tran_id >= b.tran_id
                           AND b.[date] >= '2017-07-01'
                           AND b.[date] < '2017-08-01') cs
WHERE  a.[date] >= '2017-07-01'
       AND a.[date] < '2017-08-01'
```

If you really want to know how to achieve this using `Recursive CTE` then

```
;WITH opening_balance_cte
     AS (SELECT cust_id,
                Sum(CASE WHEN tran_type = 'c' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) AS opening_balance
         FROM   @temp
         WHERE  [date] < '2017-07-01'
         GROUP  BY cust_id),
     rec_cte
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 a.*,
                      opening_balance + CASE WHEN tran_type = 'c' THEN amount ELSE -amount END AS balance
         FROM   @temp a
                JOIN opening_balance_cte o
                  ON a.cust_id = o.cust_id
         WHERE  a.[date] >= '2017-07-01'
                AND a.[date] < '2017-08-01'
         ORDER  BY a.[date] ASC
         UNION ALL
         SELECT t.*,
                rc.balance + CASE WHEN t.tran_type = 'c' THEN t.amount ELSE -t.amount END
         FROM   rec_cte rc
                JOIN @temp t
                  ON t.cust_id = rc.cust_id
                     AND t.tran_id = rc.tran_id + 1)
SELECT *
FROM   rec_cte
```

Comment: yes..this works..correct me if i am wrong but there is no way this can be done using recursive cte right?because of the group by clause..

Comment: @AnisShaikh - We can do using `Recursive CTE` but this is a better way

Comment: @AnisShaikh - Updated with `Recursive CTE` answer

Comment: yes this is what i set out to do ...did use two ctes but used aggregate in second one too..perfect..Thanks for taking out the time..@prdp

Comment: @AnisShaikh - Glad it was helpful.. have fun ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when tran_type = 'c' then amount else - amount end) over 
           (partition by cust_id order by date) as balance
from @temp t;
```

You can then select a range using a subquery or CTE:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when tran_type = 'c' then amount else - amount end) over 
                 (partition by cust_id order by date) as balance
      from @temp t
     ) t
where . . .
```

You need a subquery for the `where`, so it doesn't affect the cumulative sum.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `cross apply`:

```
select t.*,
       t2.balance
from @temp t cross apply
     (select sum(case when t2.tran_type = 'c' then t2.amount else - t2.amount end) as balance
      from @temp t2
      where t2.cust_id = t.cust_id and t2.date <= t.date
     ) t2;
```

Comment: this is helpful but i was looking for solutions in the case of SQL Server 2008